# How to remove security requirement on an apiconnect path?

Tags: node.js, apiconnect

By default apiconnect adds security to be required on all the paths. How can I allow a hit on a path without requiring authentication first?

I've tried unchecking the "Use API security definitions" in the Security section of on my User.count path, but when I use the browser on the URL https://localhost:4002/api/Users/count I get back

```
Error
401 Authorization Required
code: AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED
Error: Authorization Required
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:433:21
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\loopback\lib\model.js:359:7
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\loopback\common\models\acl.js:536:16
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3888:9
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:473:16
at iteratorCallback (D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1064:13)
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:969:16
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3885:13
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\loopback\common\models\acl.js:518:17
at D:\PeteSoft\node\test3\node_modules\loopback\common\models\role.js:447:21
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

How can I get the count returned instead of the Authorization Required error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free version, you have to include the IBM client Id  (and IBM client secret is optional)..

However, the Authorization error can be catched, so if you properly configure the catch to capture that error, you could work withouth the IBM Client id.. (it is a bad practice, but might solve your problem).

[Catch Auth Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRPlb.png)

If you want to work with out those keys, you have to buy the product, and in the Design Tab, it will allow you to remove it...